# Regular expression for checking string outside of a set

Tags: python, regex, r, scrapy

I am writing a web crawler using Scrapy and as a result I get a set of URLs like: [Dummy URLs]
*http://matrix.com/en/Zion

http://matrix.com/en/Machine_World

http://matrix.com/en/Matrix:Banner_guidelines

http://matrix.com/en/File:Link_Banner.jpg

http://matrix.com/wiki/en/index.php*

In the rules in scrapy, I want to add a regex that allows urls ONLY of the kind  "http://matrix.com/en/Machine_World" or "http://matrix.com/en/Zion"
i.e urls that contain anything outside of the set "http://matrix.com/en/<[a-zA-Z,_]>" must not be allowed.

Constraints :

- The string after "/en/" could be of any length. So I cannot ask it to look only for the first 10 or 20 characters. e.g when I use the regex : [a-zA-Z,*]{1,20} OR [a-zA-Z,*]{1,} it still matches the URLs like http://matrix.com/en/Matrix:Banner_guidelines coz it finds "http://matrix.com/en/Matrix" part of the url a successful match. I want it look at the string starting after "/en/" till the end of URL and then apply this rule. 
  Unfortunately I cannot extract that string n write a sub-routine of any kind. It has to be done using a regex only!

Comment: `http://matrix.com/en/[a-zA-Z,_]+$` ?

Comment: `$` matches "end of line"

Comment: What is the expected output from the examples given?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen added "+$" to the regex. That results in none of the URLs matching as opposed to an earlier match of all the URLs (as is the original problem)

Comment: I have mentioned the expected output in the question: "In the rules in scrapy, I want to add a regex that allows urls ONLY of the kind "http://matrix.com/en/Machine_World" or "http://matrix.com/en/Zion" i.e urls that contain anything outside of the set "http://matrix.com/en/<[a-zA-Z,_]>" must not be allowed." i.e a URL like http://matrix.com/en/Matrix:Banner_guidelines OR http://matrix.com/en/Matrix:Banner.jpg or any such kind should not be a successful match

Comment: ....interesting. Uh, guessing whitespace is causing issues. `http://matrix.com/en/[a-zA-Z,_]+\w+$`

Comment: @ NightShadeQueen That worked! I don't know why the tool I was using to verify the answers didn't show the results. I was avoiding running the crawler with different answers so as not to have my IP blocked with repeated requests. But your answer works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can mark a comment as an answer! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i.e urls that contain anything outside of the set "http://matrix.com/en/<[a-zA-Z,_]>" must not be allowed.

Have you tried using this character class in your regex?  Looks like you aren't including underscores.

Try

```
[a-zA-Z,_]+
```

The plus sign means "one or more" - which is the same as {1,} just a nice shorthand :)

If you want to exclude items with .php or .jpg, feel free to add a $ sign to the end, as so:

```
[a-zA-Z,_]+$
```

The $ means "end of line" meaning that your matching sequence must run to the end of the line.  As fullstops are not included in the character class, those options will be excluded

Let me know if that works,
Elliott

Comment: adding the "+" gives me the same result as using the length {1,20} OR {1,}

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Looks like you aren't including underscores." Another way of expressing what I want as a successful output is urls of the format http://matrix.com/en/<One_Word> OR http://matrix.com/en/<OneWord>  (using camel case only for example. Real o/p doesn't care about case)

Comment: "If you want to exclude items with .php or .jpg, feel free to add a $ sign to the end" The regex should take care of that since all it allows is a-z, A-Z and _ . So if it encounters any other character it will automatically be disqualified. Or so I assume.

Comment: Yeah, the $ means that it won't match the other two lines as they contain characters that aren't included in your character class before the end of the line

Comment: And the + is just a shorthand for {1,}.  {1,20} will only match up to 20 matching characters

Answer (score 0):

Reproducible evidence that the suggested regex works:

```
grep("matrix.com\\/en\\/[a-zA-Z,_]+$", x, perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
#[1] "http://matrix.com/en/Zion"         
#[2] "http://matrix.com/en/Machine_World"
```

**Data**

```
x <- c("http://matrix.com/en/Zion", "http://matrix.com/en/Machine_World", 
       "http://matrix.com/en/Matrix:Banner_guidelines",
       "http://matrix.com/en/File:Link_Banner.jpg",
       "http://matrix.com/wiki/en/index.php")
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. I was using an online tool to verify answers but I guess the tool is messy. But "[a-zA-Z,_]+$" seems to do the trick!